# R code using lattice package

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I've made this wonderful lake temperature profile plot though it's been a headache. I just want to add a label to the colorbar indicating the it is degrees C. Preferably the degree symbol. Here is the code and the almost finished plot!

```
levelplot(data.m, aspect="fill", 
          col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","blue","yellow","red")),
          at=seq(0,14.5,length=50), 
          ylab = "Depth (m)", xlab = "Date", 
          scales=list(x=list(at=c(9,40,70,101,132,162,193,223,254,285,313,344)),
          y=list(at=c(2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92,102))))
```

Comment: Right now it is missing the data input code, as well as the figure image. editing now to attach data file, as well as image.

Comment: Seems like a lot to copy here?